# I want to use the win32 api to create a printer dialog box but DEVMODE unable to set default

Tags: c++, winapi

I can successfully create the dialog box, and get the data of the user operation to my structure, but I can't set the value when it is opened, and it is the default printer and paper of windows every time.

For example, the `dmDeviceName` member in my `DEVMODE` is `"A"`, but it is still the default printer when I open the dialog box. I read the documentation on MSDN, the requirement is a global variable, and I can’t open it correctly even if I copy it after applying. Even if I confirm that the printer name of the `PRINTDLGA` structure passed in `PrintDlgA()` is set by me during debugging, it still doesn't work.

Below is my function. The functions after `PrintDlgA(&printDlg)` can work correctly, but `DEVMODEA` has no effect when initializing `PRINTDLGA` when it is opened.

```
inline int OpenPrintSetupDlg(DEVMODEA n_in_info, CPrintInfo* n_out_info, BOOL is_inly_set) {
    int result = PRINT_CN;
    PRINTDLGA printDlg = { 0 };
    printDlg.lStructSize = sizeof(PRINTDLGA);
    printDlg.Flags = is_inly_set ? PD_RETURNDC | PD_PRINTSETUP : PD_RETURNDC;
    HGLOBAL pdevmode = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_ZEROINIT, sizeof(DEVMODEA));

    if (!pdevmode)
    {
        return result;
    }
    printDlg.hDevMode = (PDEVMODEA)GlobalLock(pdevmode);
    if (!printDlg.hDevMode)
    {
        GlobalFree(pdevmode);
        return result;
    }
    memcpy(printDlg.hDevMode, &n_in_info, sizeof(DEVMODEA));
    //debug_put((char*)((DEVMODEA*)printDlg.hDevMode)->dmDeviceName, (char*)((DEVMODEA*)pdevmode)->dmDeviceName, (char*)n_in_info.dmDeviceName);
    //GlobalUnlock(printDlg.hDevMode);
    if (PrintDlgA(&printDlg))
    {
        if (n_out_info)
        {
            if (printDlg.hDevNames)
            {
                LPDEVNAMES lpDevNames = (LPDEVNAMES)GlobalLock(printDlg.hDevNames);
                LPSTR lpszDriver = (LPSTR)lpDevNames + lpDevNames->wDeviceOffset;
                n_out_info->m_DeviceName = CloneTextData(reinterpret_cast<char*>(lpszDriver));

            }
            if (printDlg.hDevNames) {
                PDEVMODEA    devmode = (PDEVMODEA)GlobalLock(printDlg.hDevMode);
                n_out_info->set_info(devmode);

            }
        }
        result = PRINT_OK;
    }
    if (printDlg.hDevMode)
    {
        GlobalFree(printDlg.hDevMode);
        printDlg.hDevNames = nullptr;
    }
    if (printDlg.hDevNames)
    {
        GlobalFree(printDlg.hDevNames);
        printDlg.hDevMode = nullptr;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: How are you populating the `DEVMODEA` that you are passing to `OpenPrintSetupDlg()`? Pleasse provide a [mcve].

Comment: On a side note: you are not unlocking `printDlg.hDevMode` before calling `PrintDlg()`. And you are not unlocking `printDlg.hDevNames` after using it, either. Also, you should not assign the result of `GlobalLock()` directly to `printDlg.hDevMode`, as `PrintDlg()` may reset `printDlg.hDevMode` to NULL on exit, leaking your memory. Use a local `HGLOBAL` variable instead.

Comment: *To initialize the dialog box for a different printer, use the wDeviceOffset member of the DEVNAMES structure to specify the name of the printer.*  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commdlg/ns-commdlg-printdlga

Comment: To display information for other installed printers, use the DEVNAMES structure and assign a global memory handle to the structure to the hDevMode and hDevNames members.